# Restarting self in a Topshelf service

Tags: c#, .net, topshelf

I'm using Topshelf to host a Windows service. I am looking to get the hosted service to call to have itself restarted upon certain events. I was wondering how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What do you mean by "certain events"? This question requires more description.

Comment: Agree with @RoyDictus - you can certainly get a TopShelf host to restart itself (using the HostControl interface) but how you invoke it specifically depends on your definition of an 'event'.

Comment: We implement an RPC interface to receive commands. It would be upon receipt of a certain command that the service should restart itself. I think we would rather avoid interacting directly with the Windows Services API and use Topshelf itself to relaunch the service. It sounds like I will need to do research into using the HostControl interfact. Currently I launch the service as such; HostFactory.Run(delegate). I assume I would have to change the usage of this

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call `Environment.Exit(1);` when u want restart service

then in HostFactory add Enable ServiceRecovery

```
HostFactory.Run(configure =>
            {
                configure.Service((ServiceConfigurator<Service> service) =>
                {

                    service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
                    service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
                });

                //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
                configure.RunAsNetworkService();
                configure.SetServiceName("ServiceName");
                configure.SetDisplayName("ServiceName");
                configure.SetDescription("Description");
                configure.StartAutomaticallyDelayed();
                configure.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
                {
                    recoveryOption.RestartService(0);
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service manager if you know the service name to call restart. It may or may not work called from itself. This isn't something Topshelf exposes, so you're on your own to do it.